# How to align a caption with a ragged-right subfigure keeping caption text justified

Tags: align, subfloats, subcaption

I have a problem aligning subcaptions with their corresponding subfigures. I'm using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to shift subfigures (a) and (b) to the left and right borders of the body text as shown in the image:

[image]

This works, however, the subcaptions are not aligned with the edges of their corresponding subfigures. I would like to shift the subcaptions to the edges of the page (as indicated by the green arrows) but preserving the justification of the text. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \captionsetup{width=0.90\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth,left]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub A]{
                Caption (a) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. 
            }
            \label{fig:subA}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \captionsetup{width=0.90\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth,right]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub B]{
                Caption (b) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam.
            }
            \label{fig:subB}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\[1ex]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.65\textwidth}
            \centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub C]{
                Caption (c) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
                eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
            }
            \label{fig:subC}
        \end{subfigure}
        \centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}%
        \caption[Main figure]{
            Main caption Caption (b) Donec varius orci eget
            risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
            eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
        }
        \label{fig:main} 
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the margins of the captions with `\captionsetup`, to make the width of each caption exactly that of the corresponding graphic included with `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \captionsetup{width=0.90\textwidth,margin={0mm,0.10\textwidth}}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth,left]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub A]{
                Caption (a) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. 
            }
            \label{fig:subA}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \captionsetup{width=0.90\textwidth,margin={0.10\textwidth,0mm}}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth,right]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub B]{
                Caption (b) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam.
            }
            \label{fig:subB}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\[1ex]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.65\textwidth}
            \centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
            \caption[Sub C]{
                Caption (c) Donec varius orci eget
                risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
                eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
            }
            \label{fig:subC}
        \end{subfigure}
        \centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}%
        \caption[Main figure]{
            Main caption Caption (b) Donec varius orci eget
            risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
            eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
        }
        \label{fig:main} 
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]